# The system has a non-trivial solution, find $p$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

The system 
$(p-2)x+y=0$
$x+(p-2)y=0$
has a non-trivial solution. Find $p$.

Now I found the augmented matrix in row echelon form, which is $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1&p-2&0\\
  0&1-(p-2)^2&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

However I am now confused as to how to find the non-trivial solution. What does it really mean for a solution to be trivial? Is it when $x=y=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a non-trivial solution is one for which $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ are not *both* zero.  If $\ 1-\left(p-2\right)^2\ne 0\ $ then the second row of your row-echelon form gives you $\ y=0\ $, and then the first row gives you $\ x=0\ $.  Therefore $\ 1-\left(p-2\right)^2= 0\ $ is a *necessary* condition for your original system to have a non-trivial solution.  I'll leave it for you to determine whether it's also sufficient.